# Adding properties to IdentityUser doesn't create the correct migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I've followed the tutorial here: [Customizing profile information in ASP.NET Identity in VS 2013 templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx)

And did exactly what's written there, except for that my new property is a string named 'TaxId'. Surprisingly, when I did the "Add-Migration" part, the migration file came up empty:

```
namespace Mvc5Test.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class TaxId : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        { 
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why did it happen and what's the right way to fix it? (I'd like to avoid updating the migration file manually...)

EDIT:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string TaxId { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how did you extend `IdentityUser` ?

Comment: @Ofiris I've just edited the question to show the way I'd extended `IdentityUser`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was that I've already had my own DB context.
Used this solution, taken from [here](http://www.discussiongenerator.com/2014/04/21/customizing-applicationdbcontext-in-asp-net-mvc-5-and-asp-net-identity-2-0/).

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. 3 hours of my life down the drain googling a solution to this.